# OData V4 Contains and any

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api2

We have an OData V4 endpoint with the following structure. We are using
Entity Framework 6.1, OData V4 and Web Api 2.2

```
http://api.com/odata/Companies
```

and if we want to get the address we simply expand like this

```
http://api.com/odata/Companies?$expand=Addresses
```

If I filter by city it works nice

```
http://api.com/odata/Companies?$filter=Addresses/any(a:a/City eq 'New York')
```

But we cannot apply Contains to the filter. 
What is the correct syntax to achieve Contains with the City property?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One part of the correct syntax is to have the letters of built-in query option "contains()" all in lower case, in case the reason that you failed to apply it to the filter is because the casing isn't right.

You can see the following query to the TripPin sample service as an example of the whole syntax:

```
http://services.odata.org/v4/TripPinServiceRW/People?$filter=Trips/any(a:contains(a/Name,'US'))&$expand=Trips
```

Comment: It works perfectly and actually I am wondering were did you find the DOCS for the correct syntax cause we struggle to find information about V4 complex queries

Comment: @Raffaeu For the syntax for "contains()" specifically, you can find it in section 11.2.5.1.2 of the OData V4 protocol: http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/os/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-os-part1-protocol.html#_Toc372793694. For any URL related conventions, this doc can be referred to: http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/os/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-os-part2-url-conventions.html#_Toc372793815. For more advanced scenarios, you can look up the ABNF doc: http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/os/abnf/.

Comment: Kudo ++ for this unvalueable resource :-)